# How can I install the Ubuntu 11.10 "greybird" theme on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, themes, xubuntu, xfce, greybird

How can I install the Ubuntu 11.10 "greybird" theme on Ubuntu 10.04?

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Which allows me to use Xfce, but the default "greybird" theme found in Xubuntu 11.10 (may be earlier, but that's when I first saw it) is not present.

Is there any way to install this in Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: Ubuntu and Xubuntu are not quite the same. They use different desktop components such as the window manager, file manager, panels, applets, etc. Thus a theme, designed for Xubuntu will not work in Ubuntu.

Comment: @mikewhatever Are you sure about that?  I can easily use Xubuntu 10.04 themes if I just run the above command and use the "xubuntu  session" option when logging in (I am using one now actually...).    I am pretty sure the xubuntu-desktop package includes all the dependencies you are talking about.    My question is just how to get the 11.10 version instead of the 10.04 version.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. By selecting "xubuntu-session", you load Xubuntu with all its components instead of Ubuntu, and I am not talking about dependencies, but rather about the core desktop components. On the second though, I might be wrong, since both Gnome and XFCE are Gtk based. Anyway, a quick search shows that you can get the greybird theme: http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/Themes/greybird-shiki-75965.shtml Try using it in both Ubuntu and Xubuntu and let me know how it goes. :~)

Comment: @mikewhatever Ah, sorry, I guess I am making an incorrect distinction between what is "xubuntu" and what is "ubuntu".  From what you are saying, I am actually running xubuntu.  That's fine with me, I just want to avoid doing a reinstall (this is my work machine with a lot of custom stuff set up by my employer that I'd rather not have to figure out how to set up ).  `xubuntu-session` seems to have been working fine for me for a while.  So I guess I am really just looking how to get the greybird theme from 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

The Graybird theme is available for download from Softpedia.

http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/Themes/greybird-shiki-75965.shtml

To install, extract the archive, and copy its content to /usr/share/themes/.

Comment: I just checked this out, looks like it's not quite the right theme (the greybird theme in 11.10 is all grey/silver).   I'll poke around and see if I can find the new version on that site.